# Optional part in regex pattern

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have following strings to process

```
Name ( $4 USD )
Name ( $4.1 USD )
Name ( $4.12 USD )
Name ( $4123123.02 USD )
```

I want to USD amout from them
Right now I a using follwoing regex pattern

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\( \$(?<cash>\d+\.\d{1,2}) USD \)");
```

but it does not match the first example. What should I change to make the .\d{1,2} part optional?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\( \$(?<cash>\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?) USD \)");
```

`(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, and the following `?` makes that group optional.